# Enclose text with Image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working with React native and I want to enclose text with Image.

Is there any packages or any props like this effect.(see the screenshot[image])

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give your desired output

```
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}})>
    <Image ...>
    <Text style = {{flex: 1}}>Hello</Text>
    <Image ...>
</View>
```

EDIT: Changed `alignItems`->`jusitfyContent` and added `flex: 1` to `Text` component

EDIT: Heres a solution based on your second screenshot. Note the react-native `Text` component supports subviews.

```
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}})>
    <Image ...>
    <Text style = {{flex: 1}}>Hello
        <Image ...>
    </Text> 
</View>
```

You can play around with the `CSS` props in order to position it how you want but this should work.

Comment: it's working in one row sentence. But when I use long sentence, I cannot put the image into the last part of text.

Comment: Ofcourse, i've edited my answer to give your desired result

Comment: I have changed my screenshot.